# Convert from Excel to MS SQL (DD.MM.YYYY becomes YYYY-DD-MM instead of YYYY-MM-DD)

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I have table in Excel with dates:
[image]

By VBA, I import it to ms sql server into a table:
[image]

The result is in Excel date format DD.MM.YYYY. After import the date becomes YYYY-DD-MM instead of YYYY-MM-DD.

```vb
Sub Button1_Click()
     
    Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
    Dim iRowNo As Integer
    Dim smdm_id As String, sdate_start As String, sdate_end As String
  
    With Sheets("Ââîä")
            
        'Open a connection to SQL Server
        conn.Open "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Server=actuar11;Database=marketing_sbx;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated Security=SSPI;"
            
        'Î÷èñòèì òàáëèöó
        conn.Execute "truncate table ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm"
        
        'conn.Execute "Update X Set X.date_start = TRY_CONVERT(Date, X.date_start, 103) FROM ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm X"
        'conn.Execute "Update X Set X.date_end = TRY_CONVERT(Date, X.date_end, 103) FROM ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm X"
            
        'Skip the header row
        iRowNo = 2
            
        'Loop until empty cell in CustomerId
        Do Until .Cells(iRowNo, 1) = ""
            smdm_id = .Cells(iRowNo, 1)
            sdate_start = .Cells(iRowNo, 2)
            sdate_end = .Cells(iRowNo, 3)
                
            'Generate and execute sql statement to import the excel rows to SQL Server table

            conn.Execute "insert into dbo.ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm (mdm_id, date_start, date_end) values ('" & smdm_id & "', '" & sdate_start & "', '" & sdate_end & "')"
            iRowNo = iRowNo + 1
        Loop
                                
        MsgBox "Ñòðàõîâàòåëè è äàòû èìïîðòèðîâàíû."
        
        conn.Close
        Set conn = Nothing
              
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is that help me:
Original code:

```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm (mdm_id, date_start, date_end) values ('" & smdm_id & "', '" & sdate_start & "', '" & sdate_end & "')"
```

Changed code:

```
conn.Execute "insert into dbo.ol_del_export_from_excel_macro_mdm (mdm_id, date_start, date_end) values ('" & smdm_id & "', '" & Format(sdate_start, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "', '" & Format(sdate_end, "YYYY-MM-DD") & "')"
```